# dataflow bigquery partition

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to create partitions in google bigquery with help of dataflow libraries. Does dataflow allow us to create partitions in Bigquery?
I found a link which asks the same question.[Creating/Writing to Parititoned BigQuery table via Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114306/creating-writing-to-parititoned-bigquery-table-via-google-cloud-dataflow)

I tried partition decorator `project_name:dataset_nametable_name$YYYYMMDD` but it did not help.

Comment: Yes its a duplicate but the solution in that question did not work for me

Comment: Could you please add your comment to that question?

Comment: Did you get an error with this or did it just write it to the current day's partition?

Comment: Passing table name in `table_name_YYYYMMDD` format, worked for us.