# BigqueryIO Unable to Write to Date-Partitioned Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am following the instructions in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114306/creating-writing-to-parititoned-bigquery-table-via-google-cloud-dataflow) to write to a date-partitioned table in BigQuery. I am using a serializable function to map the the window to a partition-location using the `$` syntax and I get the following error:

```
Invalid table ID \"table$19700822\". Table IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and must be at most 1024 characters long.
```

Am I missing something here?

Edit adding code:

```
p.apply(Window.<TableRow>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardDays(1))))
    .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
    .named("Write")
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    .to(new SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>() {
      public String apply(BoundedWindow window) {
        String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
             .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
             .print(((IntervalWindow) window).start());
        return "project_id:dataset.table$" + dayString;
      }
    }));
```

Comment: I don't think so because the output of the serializable function actually looks like: `project-id:dataset.table$YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Could you provide the code that you're using?

Comment: @Sonya I added the code I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the table you're trying to access already exists. You can't create a table with "$" in it, and you're using "create if needed", so that your code might end up creating the table in addition to trying to write to it.

Comment: Looks like a combination of this an using `DataflowPipelineRunner` fixed the issue.

Comment: @Narek did you manage to create a BQ table with date partition from dataflow pipeline? I have a streaming pipeline the only solution I can think of currently is stopping my pipeline when date rolls over and then starting a new streaming pipeline with table name that has updated date.

Comment: @PUG have you tried `Write.toTableReference` in 
 the newer versions?
 https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/class-use/BigQueryIO.Write.Bound.html