# Loading data into Biqquery Partitioned table through Google Dataflow/Beam with write_truncate

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So the existing setup we had use to create a new table for each day, which worked fine with ["WRITE_TRUNCATE"](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/google_cloud_platform/bigquery.py#L451) option, however when we updated our code to use partitioned table, though our dataflow job, it wouldn`t work with write_truncate.

It works perfectly fine, with write disposition set as "WRITE_APPEND" (From what i understood, from [beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2689ca43c634c2f1bc57132db4fb2391489534c4/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1534-L1539), it maybe tries to delete the table, and then recreate it), since i`m supplying the table decorator it fails to create a new table.

Sample snippet using python code:

```
beam.io.Write('Write({})'.format(date), beam.io.BigQuerySink(output_table_name + '$' + date, create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
```

which gives the error:

> Table IDs must be alphanumeric

since it tried to recreate the table, and we supply the partition decorator in the argument.

Here are some of the things that i`v tried:

1. Updating the write_disposition as WRITE_APPEND, although it works, it fails the purpose, since running for the same date again would duplicate data.
2. Using

`bq --apilog /tmp/log.txt load  --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON 'table.$20160101' sample_json.json`

command, to see if i can observe any logs, on how does truncate actually works, based on the [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#restating_data_in_a_partition) that i found.

3. Tried some other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114306/creating-writing-to-parititoned-bigquery-table-via-google-cloud-dataflow), but this as well uses WRITE_APPEND.

Is there a way to write to a partitioned table, from a dataflow job using write_truncate method?

Let me know if any additional details are required.
Thanks

Comment: The failure to create the table with the partition decorator may be a bug. Let  me check and get back to you.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace for your 'Table IDs must be alphanumeric'?

Comment: I checked with the IO dev. It seems that this is not supported now. : /

Comment: Thanks for replying Pablo :), i was only hoping it does not delete the table for TRUNCATE, and just clears all the rows, for that partition, but i guess it doesn`t work that way [beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/google_cloud_platform/bigquery.py#L939).

Comment: @Sirius digging this back up (albeit being a very old question) as I've run in a very similar scenario. Did you end up submitting a Jira card to [this][https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1743?filter=-4&jql=project%20%3D%20BEAM%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20DESC] page or solving with some other approach that wasn't discussed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not supported at this time.  *Credit goes to @Pablo for finding out from the IO dev.*

According to the [Beam documentation](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/README.md) on the Github page, their [JIRA page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1743?filter=-4&jql=project%20%3D%20BEAM%20ORDER%20BY%20createdDate%20DESC) would be the appropriate to request such a feature.  I'd recommend filing a feature request there and posting a link in a comment here so that others in the community can follow through and show their support.