# Writing to a BigQuery table with date in table name from a DataFlow streaming pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My table name format: `tableName_YYYYMMDD`. I am trying to write to this table from a streaming dataflow pipeline. The reason I want to write to a new table everyday is because I want to expire tables after 30 days and only want to keep a window of 30 tables at a time.

Current code:

```
tableRow.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                .named("WriteBQTable")
                .to(String.format("%1$s:%2$s.%3$s",projectId, bqDataSet, bqTable))
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

I do realize above code will not roll over to new day and start writing there.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38125710/384554) answer suggests I can partition table and expire partitions, but writing to a partitioned tables seems like is not supported from a streaming pipeline.

Any ideas how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dataflow 2.0 SDK there is a way to specify DynamicDestinations

See `to(DynamicDestinations<T,?> dynamicDestinations)` in [BigQuery Dynamic Destionations](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html).

Also, see the TableDestination version, which should be simpler and less code. Though unfortunately there is no example in the javadoc.

```
to(SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<T>,TableDestination> tableFunction)
```

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/

Comment: I have been testing this with a partitioned table writing from dataflow, looks like big query is assigning values correctly, I am not assigning any `_PARTITIONTIME` from dataflow. Below returns correct data. 
`SELECT * FROM Mytable  WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2017-08-04") `

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/bomboradata/pubsub-to-bigquery) is an open source pipeline you can use to connect pub/sub to big query. I think google has also added support for streaming pipelines to date partitioned tables. Details [here](http://meethassan.net/2017/08/07/streaming-writes-into-a-date-partitioned-bigquery-table-using-a-dataflow-streaming-pipeline/).