# Loading Hive partitioned table in google cloud platform's BigQuery service using dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-bigquery

Hive Partitioned Tables have a folder structure with partition date as the folder. I have explored loading externally partitioned tables directly to [bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs) which is possible.

What I would like to know is if this feature is possible to do with `dataflow` since I am going to be running some feature transforms and such using `dataflow` before loading the data into `bigquery`. what I have found is if I add the partition date as a column then [partitioning is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114306/creating-writing-to-parititoned-bigquery-table-via-google-cloud-dataflow/38137217#38137217?newreg=8a7f49c597ad4c7288c06bdcb93af3e1) but I am looking for a direct method with which I wouldn't be adding the column during transforms but directly while loading data into bigquery.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Do you want to load hive partitioned tables from Dataflow, or another kind of [partition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#top_of_page) ? Keep in mind that to use HivePartitioning the data will still need to be loaded from Google Cloud Storage, even if you process it with Dataflow

Comment: hive partitioned table using dataflow from gcs, and since it is hive partitioned table the column itself will not exist in the original data. but it should be present as a column after the data is loaded in bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

[Hive partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs) is a beta feature in BigQuery, and it was [released on Oct 31st, 2019](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#October_31_2019). The latest version of Apache Beam SDK [supported by Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status#apache-beam-2x-sdks) is [2.16.0](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2019/10/07/beam-2.16.0.html) which was released on Oct 7th, 2019. At the moment, neither [Java](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryServices.JobService.html) nor [Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig) supports this feature directly. So, if you want to use it from Dataflow, maybe you could try calling the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationload) directly